# sending data by using volley - utf8

Tags: android, mysql, utf-8, android-volley

I am using below code to send data to the server.
but when I send data,the data in the mysql are ???.How do I send data to utf 8?

```
private void sendDataToDataBase(final String fperson,final String lperson){
    RequestQueue queue = MyVolley.getRequestQueue();
    StringRequest myReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            "mylink",
            createMyReqSuccessListener(),
            createMyReqErrorListener()) {

        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("fname", fperson);
        params.put("lname", lperson);
        return params;
            };
        };
        queue.add(myReq);
}
```

Comment: how do you initialize `fperson` and `lperson` ?

Comment: I would get the value of a edit text. ex : edit_txt_fone.getText().toString().trim();

Comment: have you tried something like `Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(yourEditText.getText().toString());`

Comment: i bookmarked and try to solve it tomorrow because i will soon fall in this problem for my app;-)

Answer (score 2):

One solution that I myself use to upload data containing utf-8 strings to server (with not just Volley, but with other libraries as well) is to **encode it to Base64 and then decode it in the server**. This way I make sure the exact data is passed to the server.

This is the code I use for encoding:

```
data = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
reqBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: I used but did not differ :     byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(str.getBytes());
    text = encodedBytes.toString() ;   ===== in the server : base64_decode($text)

Comment: Check my added code and see if that works for you. Also, you can put your resulting base56 in [this site](http://www.base64decode.org/) and see if you get the expected string.

Comment: on server side you use  base64_decode($text) function ?

Comment: I think so, but since I haven't write the server side, I can't tell for sure. But if you can decode the base64 string in the site I mentioned above, there shouldn't be any problem in decoding it in PHP.

Comment: This works without pain for android but the problem is you have to decode the content in the server which is not a normal practice this can be a temp solution